# Loop Redirect after login Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a login form in symfony2

When enter correct information, the redirect enter in loop and a message: "No data received" or "Connect Reset" is showed. if i enter with wrong information, the message: Bad Credencial is showed.

My security.yml

Segue o security.yml que criei

```
 dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login_firewall:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        anonymous: ~

    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: meu_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check                
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: homepage

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The user IS ROLE_USER in $user->getRoles()

Thanks!

Sorry by my English!

Comment: why do you need the `login_firewall`? commonly one firewall is needed... try to remove that firewall (if not needed)

Answer (score 1):

In cookbook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html firewall containing login form and check path (which is the same in example) are defined in firewall which can be accessed by anonymous users.

In your config only /login is accessible (line: pattern:  ^/login$).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `anonymous: ~` to  `security: false` in **login_firewall section**

Comment: Continue...

No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

Your login and login_check routes should be under the firewall you are using.
In other words, you have to remove/comment those 3 lines:

```
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    #login_firewall:
    #    pattern:  ^/login$
    #    anonymous: ~

    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: meu_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check                
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: homepage

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

This line - `{ path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` - is enough for users being able to use login form without having a redirection loop.